# Presenting the contents of a PHP file on a cordova app

Tags: php, ios, json, cordova, xmlhttprequest

Cordova won't accept php files to be executed on the app. Below is code to display images stored on a server. The images are found through their paths stored in mySQL. I tried **XMLHTTP** to adapt my PHP file in the app but the images appear broken. I feel I need to convert the displayed images into something else possibly **JSON** messages or something? This PHP file is stored beside the image folder on the server. In the browser the images are displayed perfectly I want the same effect in the browser.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <?php
  include("mysqlconnect.php");

  $select_query = "SELECT `ImagesPath` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
  $sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
  ?>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
  <img src="<?php echo $row["ImagesPath"]; ?>" width="100" height="100" id="images"/>
  </body>
  <?php

  }
  ?>
  </html>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: why would you do it like that? why not send the image URL to phonegap app and display it there in img src?

Comment: Because the images are being uploaded on a separate PHP file. The images and the amount of images in the folder will be changing. This cordova page needs to be dynamic.

Comment: you really think you can build only static html with phonegap? you should read about angular js or backbone or ember ... and forget you thought of your solution.